# Local debugging azure emulator

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, emulation, windows-7-x64

Windows 7, VS2012-Update1, x64.

If i start e new MVC-project, and add the Azure project to it. I can't debug it locally in the azure emulator.

The error:

> Operation taking longer than expected
>
> A 64-bit debugging operation is
> taking longer than expected. This may be caused by incompatibilities
> with 3rd party networking softwar. [See help for troubleshooting these issues.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184681.aspx)

When i Terminate that message (twice):

> Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> There was en error attaching the debugger t the role intances
> 'deployment18(18).mvctest.Azure.Website_IN_0' with prces Id:'8752'.
> Unable to attach. The Microsoft Visual Studio remote debugging monitor
> has been closed on the remote machine.

The first message, I already found that if you change your website target to x86 that this can solve the problem. (this solved a problem for debugging unit-tests)
But if I change it to x86, the nex message pops up:

> Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Cannot start debugging. The role was built for a platform incompatible with the windows azure compute emulator. On this system the compute emulator supports anyCPU and x64.

If i start without debugging (not x86), the windows emulator starts, and the website opens.

Is there a solution to solve this that we can debug x64 websites on the azure emulator?

Thanks.

### Problem solved:

The issue was, that oour normal account didnt had admin privileges, and that we had to use an other admin user his credentials to run it in admin mode.
If i logged on with that admin user and started everything, that user couldn't also load the azure emulator.
Every co-developer had the same issue.
But when the normal account had back the admin privileges, the emulator started normally.
So i assume that there was something missing for those admin account (what i don't know)

Comment: Is it possible one of your referring dll's are compiled for 32bit?

Comment: I dont think so, unless  a new mvc project referes to 32bit dll's

Comment: Ok. Just re-read your question and what first comes to mind is that you have seemd tochange to x86 to make it pass the first problem. Right click your project and select Any CPU as "Platform" and "Platform target".

Comment: What are the "Attach to:" set to in the Attach to process gui?http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/87038

Comment: Hi Magnus, i found my "problem". When we ran the VS2012 in Admin mode we had a different ADMIN user than the user we were logged in to. Apperently that ADMIN user have something missing(what i don't know) that was causing this error. Even when logged on with that admin user, i couldnt run it.
But when my normal account had back Admin privileges i could run it.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Thats great Bruno! Bet that admin user had a vpn or some conflicting driver installed :)

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the remote debugging service and the machine debug manager (for x64) are properly installed and running (services in Automatic, especially not disabled).

You can also try to download and reinstall the remote debugging tools following instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx)

Even if it is on the same machine, chances are that debugging for the emulator goes through the remote debugging path

Answer (score 1):

Been googleing this for a while now and it looks like the problem is connected to network drivers installed on windows. Do you have a VPN installed? Uninstall it and try again. 
Otherwise it could be some of the network card drivers. Same here, uninstall and try again. 
Some people have solved this by upgrading visual studio.